# Как автоматически подставить имя файла в ссылку на него?

Tags: javascript

Возникла необходимость решить такую задачу. На сервере имеется отдельная папка с одним единственным файлов в ней. Раз в неделю этот файл будет меняться. В качестве имени файла будет использоваться дата его создания. Файл такого вида: 00.00.0000.pdf. На одной из страниц сайта имеется простой код, для выведения этого pdf и его же скачивания:

```
<a href="./folder1/folder2/folder3/name.pdf" download="">СКАЧАТЬ</a>
<iframe src="./folder1/folder2/folder3/name.pdf" width="100%" height="600" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Вопрос заключается вот в чём. Как бы сделать так, чтобы имя pdf-файла подставлялось вместо name в ссылках на него автоматически. Реализовать нужно как-то по-проще и с помощью JavaScript. По некоторым причинам, использовать php-подход не представляется возможным. А мои познания в JavaScript безнадёжно стремятся к нулю. Прошу вашей квалифицированной помощи.

Comment: Да никак не получится. Сервер настраивай.

Comment: а почему нельзя заменять файл не меняя его имени? зачем сложности?!

Comment: это под силу серверной части только. Если в php не подходит, используйте perl или LUA расширения для nginx.

Answer (score 2):

Если браузер может получить доступ к этому файлу, то, я полагаю, сможет и к файлу, который лежит рядом.

Я предлагаю создать txt или любой другой файл и писать имя PDF в него, том месте где этот файл перезаписывается.

А при загрузке страницы его считывать при помощи js примерно так:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', './folder1/folder2/folder3/index.txt', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var fileName =  xhr.responseText;
         document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += `
            <a href="./folder1/folder2/folder3/${fileName}" download="">СКАЧАТЬ</a>
            <iframe src="./folder1/folder2/folder3/${fileName}" width="100%" height="600" style="border: none;"></iframe>
            `;
    }
};
xhr.send();
```